# Two-dimensional momentum

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose a particle travels with velocity $v$ in both the $x$ and $y$ direction. Its velocity along the $x$-$y$ line is $\sqrt{2}v$. Its momentum along the $x$-$y$ line is

$$p_{xy} = \frac{\sqrt{2}v}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{(\sqrt{2}v)^2}{c^2}}}$$

What is its momentum in the $x$ and $y$ directions? Does momentum obey the triangle equality?

Answer (score 0):

The energy-momentum four-vector $\textbf{P}$ has the following components in a frame in which its velocity is $v_x \hat{i}+v_y \hat{j}+v_z \hat{k}$ :

$\Bigg(\dfrac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}, \dfrac{mv_x}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}, \dfrac{mv_y}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}},\dfrac{mv_z}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}\Bigg)$

Thus, it can be seen that the spatial part of the four-momentum is a three-vector. Because if one changes (only) the orientation of the spatial axes then $m$ and $v$ would remain the same and the components of this three vector would simply transform as the components of $\vec{V}$. So yes, the spatial components of the four-momentum are the components of a three vector and the spatial part of the four-momentum will follow all the ordinary vector algebra rules such as triangle law or parallelogram law.

Thus, in your case, the $p_x$ and $p_y$ would be simply $\dfrac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2v^2}{c^2}}}$ and $\dfrac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2v^2}{c^2}}}$ respectively.